# How sets avoid duplicates internally in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, set

What happens when we try to add duplicate to a Set?

Does set check that element is present or not then it will decide whether to add or not?

Or it will overwrite the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `help` for `set.add`

```
>>> help(set.add)
Help on method_descriptor:

add(...)
    Add an element to a set.
    
    This has no effect if the element is already present.
```

Therefore trying to insert an element already contained in the set will keep the existing element, and discard the new one that is trying to be inserted.

Comment: The added variable also has to be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable),  or it cannot be added to the set. The shorthand you can use to determine if the variable can be inserted into a set, is if the variable itself is immutable or not. If it is, then it can be added.